# The pdf of the product of two variables

Tags: probability

[image]

I agree with this formula up to, but not including, the 1/|x| part. I don't see why that is that necessary?, I think the first part is sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to calculate the joint density of $(X, XY)$ and then integrate with respect to $x$ to get the density of $XY$. The map $f: (\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})^2 \to (\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\})^2, (x, y) \mapsto (x, xy)$ has inverse $f^{-1}(x, y) = (x, y/x)$. This means that the Jacobi matrix of the inverse is given by $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ -x^{-2} && x^{-1}\end{pmatrix}$, which in turn means that the determinant is $\frac{1}{x}$.

Applying the [density transformation theorem](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Probability/Transformation_of_Probability_Densities#Invertible_Transformation_of_a_Random_Vector_.28n.3Dm.29) we know that the joint density of $(X, XY)$ is now given by
$$f_{X, Y}\left(x, \frac{y}{x}\right) \frac{1}{|x|}$$